# define tab completion helper function to use in several completion files (zsh)

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I am writing zsh completion functions for a couple of commands from the same toolkit.

The commands are different enough that I want to write different completions for them in different files. (i.e. the completion for `do_thingA` is in a file `_do_thingA` with a `#compdef do_thingA` header, and the completion for `do_thingB` is in `_do_thingB` with `#compdef do_thingB`).

As different as they are, the commands all have one argument in common. So with all the things that differ between the commands, at some point all `_do_thing` files contain something along the lines

```
...
_arguments \
...
  '-c[common option]:common option:_helper_function' \
...
```

I would like to avoid having the same `_helper_function` defined in all `_do_thing` files. And on top I would like to allow users to provide their own (better personalised `_helper_function`).

What's the best way to achieve this?

### things considered:

#### definition guard

I already know that I can prevent myself from overwriting the `_helper_function` if it is already defined with

```
(( $+functions[_helper_function] )) ||
_helper_function() {
  ...
}
```

which I could put into every of the `_do_thing` files. But I would prefer outsourcing the `_helper_function` into a separate `_helper_function` file.

#### putting function body in separate file

If I create a file `_helper_function` (and have it somewhere in the `fpath`) its content will become the function body of a `_helper_function` function. In this scenario I don't see how to put the definition guard around the `_helper_function()` header (since I don't write it myself anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to place `_helper_function` somewhere in `fpath` and then in `.zshrc`

```
autoload -U _helper_function
```

Then if the user wants to customize it they merely place a new `_helper_function` file into `fpath` such that their version is found before yours, e.g. into a `firstfuncdir`:

```
% cd
% mkdir firstfuncdir
% fpath=(~/firstfuncdir $fpath)
% print -l $fpath
/Users/jhqdoe/firstfuncdir
/Users/jhqdoe/.zsh/functions/darwin
/Users/jhqdoe/.zsh/functions
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/opt/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/opt/local/share/zsh/5.5.1/functions
%
```